# LDUR and STUR in ARM v8

Tags: assembly, arm, armv8

I've had a couple of courses that touched on ARMv8 assembly, but both teachers described LDUR/STUR instructions a different way and now I've become pretty lost.  Can someone help to clarify?

If I had the instruction:

```
LDUR R3, [R1, #8]
```

I'll be putting the answer in R3, but what am I taking from R1 and how does the offset operate?  Is it like a logical shift?  The ARM manual describes it as "byte offset" but then doesn't describe how that offset functions on R1.  Do I shift the value stored in R1 (say R1 has value 50 in it) or is there a memory address outside of the R1 that I need to be thinking about?  Other sources say I need to think of R1 as an array somehow?

Comment: The answers below do explain it, but I think the main difference for programmers is that `LDUR` sign-extends the offset, so that negative offsets can be used.  `LDR` zero-extends, so that only positive offsets work.  (Not counting the pre- and post-increment forms.)  It is also true that `LDUR` allows arbitrary offsets that need not be a multiple of 2/4/8 for 16/32/64-bit loads respectively, but that would mainly be useful for unaligned loads which are relatively rare in practical code.

Answer (score 26):

LDUR is *Load (unscaled) Register*. It loads a value (32-bits or 64-bits) from an address plus an offset to a register. `unscaled` means that in the machine-code, the offset will **not** be encoded with a scaled offset like `ldr` uses, i.e. no shift will be applied to the immediate offset bits. The offset (*simm* signed immediate) will be added to the base register *Xn|SP*.

**Thus it's possible to use displacements that aren't a multiple of 4 or 8 with `ldur`, unlike with `ldr`**

These are the prototypes for LDUR:

```
    -- loads a 32-bit value
    LDUR <Wt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<simm>}]

    -- loads a 64-bit value
    LDUR <Xt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<simm>}]
```

STUR is *Store (unscaled) Register* and works in the same way but it stores the value in a register to memory.

These are the prototypes for STUR:

```
    -- stores a 32-bit register
    STUR <Wt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<simm>}]

    -- stores a 64-bit register
    STUR <Xt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<simm>}]
```

LDUR/STUR allow accessing 32/64-bit values when they are **not** aligned to the size of the operand. For example, a 32-bit value stored at address 0x52.

---

In your example,

```
    LDUR R3, [R1, #8]
```

this instruction will load to `R3` the value pointed by `R1` plus `8` bytes. This is what the ARM Reference Manual means by `byte offset`.
So if  `R1` holds the value `0x50`, this will load the value stored at address `0x58`. The value of `R1` will not be modified.

---

The instruction `LDR R3, [R1, #8]` (*LDR (immediate)* the *Unsigned offset* variant) produces the same operation, however, the prototype is different:

```
-- loads a 32-bit value
LDR <Wt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<pimm>}]

-- loads a 64-bit value
LDR <Xt>, [<Xn|SP>{, #<pimm>}]
```

The immediate offset *pimm* is different, *LDUR* uses a *simm*. This means that the offset is interpreted in a different way. The first (*pimm*) is a positive offset and its range is different for the 32-bit variant and the 64-bit variant.

In the 32 bit version:

- It ranges from 0 to 16380 and can only be a multiple of 4

In the 64 bit version:

- It ranges from 0 to 32760 and can only be a multiple of 8

**This means that some of the offsets combinations of LDUR and LDR (immediate) are going to produce the same operation.**

Comment: could you give an example where the same offset produce different results on both instructions? This part ins't clear

Comment: In the case of the LDR/STR (immediate) the Unsigned offset variant, the number stored  in the _imm12_ field is treated differently on the 32- and 64-bit variant. The imm12 field is multiply by 4 (in the 32-bit variant) and by 8 in the 64-bit variant and then is added to Wn/Xn. In that case the result will be different. Hopefully this is the part that was not clear. Let me know.

Comment: on godbolt.org, when I read `stur    w0, [x29, #-4]`, is that `#-4` already multiplied or I should multiply to see in which offset it'd go?

Comment: Compiler Explorer shows you the instruction with all the fields interpreted for you, the offsets shown are already multiplied.
In the case of `stur` the field is not multiplied, but if it were LDR then it will be.

Answer (score 1):

## Instruction Meaning

`LDUR R3, [R1, #8]`

if:

`R1=50`

then:

- `[R1, #8]` = value of address for **58** (=`50` + `#8`)
- `LDUR R3, [R1, #8]` = Load value of address for **58** to `R3` register

## Q&A

> but what am I taking from R1 and how does the offset operate?

offset `#8` operate normally, just: `R1` + `#8` = `50 + 8` = `58`

> Is it like a logical shift?

no any logical shift.

> The ARM manual describes it as "byte offset" but then doesn't describe how that offset functions on R1.

ARM manual is here: [LDUR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-Data-Transfer-Instructions/LDUR), the full description is

> LDUR  Wt, [Xn|SP{, #simm}]    ; 32-bit general registers
> ...
> simm
> Is the optional signed immediate byte offset, in the range -256 to 255, defaulting to 0.

I have same confusion same with you before. now clear:

## Detail Explanation

### LDR

Function: Load Register (immediate)

syntax

```
LDR Wt, [Xn|SP], #simm ; 32-bit general registers, Post-index
LDR Xt, [Xn|SP], #simm ; 64-bit general registers, Post-index
LDR Wt, [Xn|SP, #simm]! ; 32-bit general registers, Pre-index
LDR Xt, [Xn|SP, #simm]! ; 64-bit general registers, Pre-index

LDR Wt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ; 32-bit general registers
LDR Xt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ; 64-bit general registers
```

->

- 32-bit general registers

  - simm

    - Post-index

      - LDR Wt, [Xn|SP], #simm ;
    - Pre-index

      - LDR Wt, [Xn|SP, #simm]!
  - pimm

    - LDR Wt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ;
- 64-bit general registers

  - simm

    - Post-index

      - LDR Xt, [Xn|SP], #simm ;
    - Pre-index

      - LDR Xt, [Xn|SP, #simm]! ;
  - pimm

    - LDR Xt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ;

-》

- 32-bit / 64-bit general registers

  - simm

    - Post-index

      - LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP], #simm ;
    - Pre-index

      - LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP, #simm]!
  - pimm

    - LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ;

Note:

- value range

  - simm：`-256 ~ 255`
  - pimm

    - 32-bit : `0 ~ 16380`

      - but is must mutilple of 4, that is: `pimm % 4 == 0`
    - 64-bit : `0 ~ 32760`

      - but is must mutilple of 8, that is: `pimm % 8 == 0`

### LDUR

Function: Load register (unscaled offset)

syntax:

```
LDUR  Wt, [Xn|SP{, #simm}]    ; 32-bit general registers
LDUR  Xt, [Xn|SP{, #simm}]    ; 64-bit general registers
```

->

- 32-bit / 64-bit general registers

  - LDUR  Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #simm}]

Note:

- value range

  - simm：`-256 ~ 255`

### LDUR vs LDR

Let's talk about LDR first:

It supports 3 ways to get value

- The first type: LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP], #simm ;

  - called: Post-index
- Second: LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP, #simm]!

  - called: Pre-index
- The third type: LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}] ;

Note:

The commonly used writing method here is: the third:

`ldur q0, [x19, #0xa8]`

which is:

The last part is:

`[register name, #immediate data]`

And: LDUR also supports the third type (the first and second types are not supported)

Then comes the difference:

- The third type of LDR: `LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #pimm}]`

  - pimm value range:
    *Different cases
    * 32-bit: `0 ~ 16380`, and `pimm % 4 == 0` (is a multiple of 4)
    * 64-bit: `0 ~ 32760`, and `pimm % 8 == 0` (is a multiple of 8)

    - Key point: **MUST** be a multiple of so-and-so (4 or 8)
- LDUR: LDUR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #simm}]

  - simm value range: `-256 ~ 255`

    - Important: **NO** need to be a multiple of so-and-so (4 or 8)

-> must be a multiple of 4 (or 8), which is called:

**offset (i.e. imm here) is scaled by 4 (or 8)**

-> Here:

- scale=scale = a multiple of= is a multiple of so-and-so

  - Must be a multiple of 4 or 8

    - So when addressing, it must be 4 bytes or 8 bytes to address
- unscale=unscaled = not necessarily a multiple of so-and-so

  - Not necessarily a multiple of 4 or 8

    - So when addressing, it does not have to be 4-byte or 8-byte addressing

      - Can be addressed by one byte by oneself = addressing byte by byte

-》

- LDR=LoaD Register = LoaD (Scaled) Register = Load scaled immediate value into register
- LDUR=LoaD Unscaled Register = load unscaled immediate value into register

-> which is:

Syntax of LDR and LDUR:

`LDR Wt/Xt, [Xn|SP{, #imm}]`

the core differences are:

- value of imm

  - The value range is different

    - LDR: relatively large (32-bit 0~16380, 64-bit 0~32760), and all positive numbers
    - LDUR: relatively small, only -256~255, and can be positive or negative
  - Numerical requirements vary

    - LDR: imm must be a multiple of so-and-so

      - Depending on the platform, 32-bit or 64-bit, 4 or 8

        - 32-bit: imm%4==0
        - 64-bit: imm%8==0
    - LDUR: imm does not need to be a multiple of so-and-so

### Diff Meaning in Real Case

The difference is found, that:

- Q: What is the difference between LDR and LDUR corresponding to the actual usage meaning or scenario?
- A: If you want to address byte by byte (and the range does not exceed -256-255), you can only use LDUR, that is, the minimum moving unit of imm is 1

  - Otherwise, LDR cannot be used, because imm in LDR must be at least a multiple of 4 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

From [Arm® A64 Instruction Set Architecture: Armv8, for Armv8-A architecture profile](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0596/a/a64-base-instructions-alphabetic-order/ldur-load-register-unscaled)

```
if HaveMTEExt() then
boolean is_load_store = MemOp_LOAD IN {MemOp_STORE, MemOp_LOAD};
SetNotTagCheckedInstruction(is_load_store && n == 31);

bits(64) address;
bits(datasize) data;

if n == 31 then
    CheckSPAlignment();
    address = SP[];
else
    address = X[n];

address = address + offset;

data = Mem[address, datasize DIV 8, AccType_NORMAL];
X[t] = ZeroExtend(data, regsize);
```

this pseudo-code shows how does the offset operates is applied.

Answer (score 0):

In unsigned offset mode, LDR's imm should keep 4 byte or 8 byte align.

If imm % 4 == 0, stur Wt, [Xn|SP, #imm] is equal to str Wt, [Xn|SP, #imm] in A32.

If imm % 8 == 0, stur Xt, [Xn|SP, #imm] is equal to str Xt, [Xn|SP, #imm] in A64.

LDR can not addressing from -256 to 255 byte by byte while keeping the base register unchanged. That's what LDUR does.