# ARm prfm and prfum instructions

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, prefetch, addressing-mode

can someone explain what is the difference between the arm instructions prfm and prfum and usage of these ?

PRFUM
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/b/PRFUM

PRFM
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-Data-Transfer-Instructions/PRFM--literal-

Comment: Same as the difference between `ldr` and `ldur`, I think.  [LDUR and STUR in ARM v8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52894765).  Or is the scale factor `1` anyway, like for byte loads?  In that case no diff?

Comment: The manuals don't go into detail on the machine code, but PRFM mentions a +-1MiB offset from the current position, so maybe it's using line-size as the scale factor with PC-relative instead of a register.

Comment: what part of the arm documentation do you not understand?  please post the confusing sections and what you think they mean or dont mean

Answer (score 4):

For questions like this, your primary source is the ARMv8 Architecture Reference manual. I happen to have the edition E.a at hand, so page numbers are going to refer to that edition.

On Page C6-1136, `PRFM` (immediate) is described. It allows to prefetch data that is at an offset that is a multiple of 8 in the range of 0 to +32760 relative to the value in a base register.

On Page C6-1142, `PRFUM` is described. It allows to prefetch data that is at any kind of offset (not just multiples of 8) in the range -256 to +255 relative to the value in a base register.

So if you need (for some reasons, like working with strings) to prefetch with byte accuracy, or you need to prefetch with a negative offset, you have to use `PRFUM`. On the other hand, if you want to prefetch with an offset of 256 or higher, you have to use `PRFM`.

Comment: At least the GNU assembler will automatically encode `PRFUM` if you write something like `PRFM PLDL1KEEP, [X0, #37]`, so you don't actually have to pay attention to the distinction.  You can just think of it as two different addressing modes available to `PRFM`.  It does the same with `LDR/LDUR`, `STR/STUR`.

Comment: So this is another example of the official ARM instuctions providing a 1:1 mapping between binary opcodes and assembly language source text. There are two ways to encode an operation that can be described by `PRFM PLDL1KEEP, [X0, #32]`. To provide unique disassembler output, one of the encodings is called `PRFM`, whereas the other one is called `PRFUM`. For convenience, helpful assemblers like gas unify the two instructions with different addressing capabilities so the programmer doesn't have to worry.